# How to convert group by to partition by Sql begineer

Tags: mysql

My Query which of group by which is working fine

```
select uid,count(*) from user_details where uid  <> '' group by uid
```

Trying to convert to partition by
My query with partion by which is not as expected

`select uid,(count(uid) OVER (
        PARTITION BY uid
    )) counts from user_details where uid  <> ''`

no error message output is not correct.

```
 uid, Count As |
 Dates_not_found, 1,192 |
 Dates_not_found, 1,192 |
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: partition by is not working

Comment: What version? What error message?

Comment: no error message count is not correct. `uid,
Count As |
Dates_not_found,
1,192 |
Dates_not_found,
1,192 |`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` : You query will write the output of count result to each row, If you get the unique rows from that then you need to use `DISTINCT` to get results without duplicates.

**[FIDDLE DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33587209015f3feb95e0f32c8496f443)**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT uid,(count(uid) OVER (PARTITION BY uid)) Counts 
FROM user_details 
WHERE uid  <> ''
```